# Juju Openstack Install Won't Run on Only One Node

Tags: juju, openstack, cloud

I'm trying to install Openstack on only one node, and I tried using the openstack-charmer lxd method, but the issue is that they seem to launch 3 times ceph-osd and ceph-mon machines. I modified the script to only launch one of everything([repo here](https://github.com/stanleyshly/openstack-on-lxd)).

However, the when checking juju, the ceph-osd says that it is still looking for 3 ceph-osd peers, and the whole install fails. Any ways to modify the juju openstack install script to not look for any other peers?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible (apparently), but not advised, to not run three ceph-mon units and three ceph-osd units. I've seen strange things happen. But if you want to try then you need to change the following configuration options of the ceph-mon charm:

1. [`monitor-count`](https://opendev.org/openstack/charm-ceph-mon/src/branch/master/config.yaml#L86-L98)
2. [`expected-osd-count`](https://opendev.org/openstack/charm-ceph-mon/src/branch/master/config.yaml#L120-L130)

For example:

```
juju config ceph-mon monitor-count=1
juju config ceph-mon expected-osd-count=1
```

Comment: This is a comment not an answer to the question.